# javascript find protocol, domain, plus first slash with regexp from a src tag, replace with empty string

Tags: javascript, regex

I tried to construct a regex for this task but I'm afraid I am still failing to have an intuitive understanding of regexp.

The problem is the regex matches until the last slash in a string. I want it to stop at the first match of the string.

My pathetic attempt at regex:

```
/^http(s?):\/\/.+\/{1}/
```

Test subject:

```
http://foo.com/bar/test/foo.jpeg
```

The goal is to obtain `bar/test/foo.jpeg`, so that I may then split the string, pop the last element and then join the remainder, resulting in having the path to the JavaScript file.

**Example**

```
var str = 'http://foo.com/bar/test/foo.jpeg';
str.replace(regexp,'');
```

Comment: Create a location object and you get all for free

Comment: @mplungjan not if the browser doesn't support `location.origin` property.

Comment: what do you mean? He is not asking for origin

Comment: I deleted my answer since you obviously have decided only RegEx can solve it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While the other answer shows how to *match* a part of a string, I think a *replace* solution is more appropriate for the current task.

The issue you have is that `.+` matches one or more characters other than a newline **greedily**, that is, all the string is grabbed first in one go, and then the regex engine starts backtracking (moving backwards along the input string looking for a `/` to accommodate in the match). Thus, you get the match from `http` until the last `/`.

**To restrict the match from `http` to the first `/` use a *negated character class* `[^/]+` instead of `.+`**.

```
^https?:\/\/[^\/]+\/
            ^^^^^^
```

See [the regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/wB5cC2/2)

Note that you do not need to place `s` into a capturing group to make it optional, unescaped `?` is a quantifier that makes the preceding character match one or zero times. Also, `{1}` is a redundant quantifier since this is default behavior, `c` will only match 1 `c`, `(?:something)` will only match one `something`.

```js
var re = /^https?:\/\/[^\/]+\//; 
var str = 'http://foo.com/bar/test/foo.jpeg';
var result = str.replace(re, '');
document.getElementById("r").innerHTML = result;
```

```html
<div id="r"/>
```

Note that you will need to assign the replace result to some variable, since in JS, strings are immutable.

*Regex explanation*:

- `^` - start of string
- `https?` - either `http` or `https` substring
- `:\/\/` - a literal sequence of `://`
- `[^\/]+` - 1 or more characters other than a `/`
- `\/` - a literal `/` symbol

Comment: r3wt commented on my deleted question that he wanted to handle relative and absolute links too

Answer (score 2):

Use capturing group based regex.

```
> var s = "http://foo.com/bar/test/foo.jpeg"
> s.match(/^https?:\/\/[^\/]+((?:\/[^\/]*)*)/)[1]
'/bar/test/foo.jpeg'
```

Comment: it would fail if the sub-string was missing. do you understand this? therefor the index at `[1]` would be undefined.

Comment: ya, that's what you expected .. not?

Comment: i asked specifically using the replace function... i understand that you are not an english speaker, but at the end of the day your regex worked so thank you for your time.

Comment: you may check this `s.replace(/^(https?:\/\/[^\/]+)((?:\/[^\/]*)*)/, "$1 $2").split(' ')[1]` also.

Comment: no worries, i was able to make the first one work: https://jsfiddle.net/r3wt/wvhg38wn/